# How to merge a dict into nested dict in python with particular format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary as:

```
digit = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3, 'four' : 4, 'five' : 5 }
```

I want the new nested dictionary to be made like this:

```
new_dict = [{'eng':'one','math': 1}
            {'eng':'two','math': 2}
            {'eng':'three','math': 3}
            {'eng':'four','math': 4}
            {'eng':'five','math': 5}
           ]
```

I tried this:

```
digit = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3, 'four' : 4, 'five' : 5 }
new_dict={'eng':'','math':''}

for nest_key,nest_val in new_dict.items():
    for (key,value),(k,v) in nest_val.items(), digit.items():
        if nest_val['eng'] == '':
            nest_val.update({k:v})  
        nest_val.append({k:v})

print(new_dict)
```

Gives this error:

```
  for (key,value),(k,v) in nest_val.items(), digit.items():  
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Why must life be so complicated? It would seem `new_dict = [{'eng' : k, 'math' : v} for k, v in digit.items()]` works well.

Comment: `nest_val` is actually the value which is a string and doesn't have an `items()` method.

Comment: @coldspeed right that should have thought simply . Yet thanks for your response.

Comment: @Kasramvd ok i got confused myself with dictionary mentioned [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary). Yet thanks.

Comment: @coldspeed the answer keeps changing meaning that sometimes `'eng'` becomes key, sometimes `'math'` ! ?

Comment: @Rex5 dictionaries are un-ordred on older versions of python. It's to be expected.

Comment: @ coldspeed can we avoid the above anyhow on python 3.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, `nest_val` is actually the value which is a string and doesn't have an `items()` method. Besides that, you don't have to create another dictionary and update it by multiple loops like that. Instead, you can create your desire dictionaries by one loop over the items.

```
lst = []
for name, val in digit.items():
    lst.append({'eng': name,'math': val})
```

And in a more Pythonic way you can just use a list comprehension to refuse appending to the list at each iteration.

```
lst = [{'eng': name,'math': val} for name, val in digit.items()]
```

Comment: Alternative syntax which is more usable if you have a large number of keys: `[dict(zip(('eng', 'math'), vals)) for vals in digit.items()]`

Comment: @jpp Maybe if you could make it all functional (specially with builtins) it would be much more Pythonic :).

Comment: Thanks for the "pythonic" code. That really helps ! @Kasramvd .

Comment: Would there be problem in this way for large number of keys ? @jpp

Comment: @Rex5 Welcome. If it works you can accept the answer.

Comment: @Rex5, Yes, this will work for lots of keys. You should accept the answer btw.

Comment: @Rex5 About jpp's suggestion it'd be slower than a my list comprehension-based answer. Basically using built-in functions is will boost the performance if you use it with another built-in functions to have a really C level chain. Otherwise, due to the fact that a chain is only as strong as its weakest link there's no advantage in using them instead of a list comprehension, in terms of run time performance.

Comment: that's profound insight . Accepted answer.  @jpp :) Pls correct variable name "last"

Comment: the answer keeps changing meaning that sometimes 'eng' becomes key, sometimes 'math' ! ?